# Google maps api v2 dont work when published

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, release, keytool

I've made an app with google maps api v2. Everything seems to work fine, when i build .apk and install it's still working, but when i upload it on google play and download from there, maps are not working. I think something is wrong with those keys (who start with Alza). I know there are 2 tipes: debug and release. I tried making release key, but i think it still makes that key debug, but that just my opinion i'am still not 100% sure what's the problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate SHA1 from the certified keystore which you used to sign the android apk build. Obtaining the google map key using this SHA1 and pass it in the Google Map and API console.